# Bind event to all "select" dropdownlist elements

Tags: jquery

I have a form with a variable amount of "select" dropdownlists and textboxes. I want to bind the `.change()` event to only the "select" elements. I've tried `$(":input").change()` but binds the `.change()` event to all the inputs. Is there something like `$(":text")` or a way to specify the `$(":input")` to only target "select" elements?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$("select").change(function() { ... })
```

The selector you pass to the `$()` function can be any CSS selector, including just an html tagname such as "select".

Further reading:

- [jQuery tutorials](http://docs.jquery.com/Tutorials)
- [CSS selectors tutorial](http://css.maxdesign.com.au/selectutorial/)
- [The 30 CSS Selectors you Must Memorize](http://net.tutsplus.com/tutorials/html-css-techniques/the-30-css-selectors-you-must-memorize/)